# Tensorflow_callback ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm classifying images into two classes using binary crossentropy. So, when I'm trying to wrap my keras model with it, I get the error:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))
```

Please help. My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

# os.path.join('Train', 'benign', 'malignant')

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

import cv2
import imghdr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data_dir = ['Train', 'Test', 'Validation']
image_exts = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp']
# print(os.listdir(data_dir))
# print(os.listdir(os.path.join(data_dir, 'benign')))

'''
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(data_dir, 'benign', 'image_7.jpg'))
print(img)
print(img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
'''
for i in data_dir:
    for image_class in os.listdir(i): 
        for image in os.listdir(os.path.join(i, image_class)):
            image_path = os.path.join(i, image_class, image)
            try: 
                img = cv2.imread(image_path)    # Opening up an image (opens as numpy array)
                tip = imghdr.what(image_path)
                if tip not in image_exts: 
                    print('Image not in ext list {}'.format(image_path))
                    os.remove(image_path)
            except Exception as e: 
                print('Issue with image {}'.format(image_path))

import numpy as np
```

data1 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('Train', shuffle=True)     # Building data pipeline
data2 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('Test', shuffle=True)     # Building data pipeline
data3 = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('Validation', shuffle=True)     # Building data pipeline
data_iterator1 = data1.as_numpy_iterator()        # Helps in accessing data pipeline
data_iterator2 = data2.as_numpy_iterator()
data_iterator3 = data3.as_numpy_iterator()
batch1 = data_iterator1.next()            # Accessing data pipeline
batch2 = data_iterator2.next()
batch3 = data_iterator3.next()
# print(batch3[1])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, img in enumerate(batch1[0][:4]):
ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
ax[idx].title.set_text(batch1[1][idx])

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, img in enumerate(batch2[0][:4]):
    ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
    ax[idx].title.set_text(batch2[1][idx])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, img in enumerate(batch3[0][:4]):
    ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
    ax[idx].title.set_text(batch3[1][idx])

''' Preprocessing Data '''
# Scaling Data
data1 = data1.map(lambda x,y: (x/255, y))
data1.as_numpy_iterator().next()[0].max()

data2 = data2.map(lambda x,y: (x/255, y))
data2.as_numpy_iterator().next()[0].max()

data3 = data3.map(lambda x,y: (x/255, y))
data3.as_numpy_iterator().next()[0].max()

train_size = int(len(data1))
val_size = int(len(data3))
test_size = int(len(data2))

train = data1.take(train_size)
val = data3.take(val_size)
test = data2.take(test_size)

''' Deep Model '''
# The Network
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, AveragePooling2D, Concatenate

def vgg(input_shape, n_classes):
  
  input = Input(input_shape)
  
  x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(input)
  x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = MaxPool2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = MaxPool2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = MaxPool2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = MaxPool2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
  x = MaxPool2D(2, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
  
  x = Flatten()(x)
  x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
  x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
  
  output = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
  
  model = Model(input, output)
  return model

input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
n_classes = 2
model = vgg(input_shape, n_classes)
model.compile('adam', loss=tf.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

# Train
logdir='logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
hist = model.fit(train, epochs=20, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
print(hist.history)
```

Comment: Did you one-hot encode the data class labels?

Comment: You are using BinaryCrossentropy which expects a single class label but your final Dense layer has 2 neurons. Instead it should be `Dense(1)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `CategoricalCrossentropy` and leave the Dense layer as-is.

Comment: It's a common question. I suggest using the search function next time.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot @pavel. I will definitely do so.